# airflow command not found when installing in Ubuntu via WSL - how to add it to path?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.10.6 on WSL.

I have been trying to install airflow, and am getting 'airflow: command not found' when I'm trying to do 'airflow initdb' or 'airflow info'.
I have done

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
```

and when I run

```
myname@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:/root$ ls -l ~/.local/bin
```

I can see airflow in the list of files.

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myname myname 4096 Nov 20 14:17 __pycache__
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myname myname 3472 Nov 20 14:17 activate-global-python-argcomplete
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myname myname  215 Nov 20 14:17 airflow
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myname myname  213 Nov 20 14:17 alembic
```

when I run this command to see where my python is, I can see this

```
myname@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:/root$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Aug 18 11:39 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Aug 18 11:39 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.10-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5912936 Nov  2 18:53 /usr/bin/python3.10
```

I also warnings similar to this:

```
 WARNING: The script pygmentize is installed in '/home/myname/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
```

So I need to find a way to add this directory to PATH.
I have found the following advice from the airflow documentation,

```
If the airflow command is not getting recognized (can happen on Windows when using WSL), then ensure that ~/.local/bin is in your PATH environment variable, and add it in if necessary:

PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

am not quite sure how to do it?

I also have a MySQL workbench/server 8.0.31 installed and want to connect it to airflow instead of SQLite. can anybody refer me to a good guide on how to install it correctly?
I have run 'pip install 'apache-airflow[mysql]'.

Comment: Did you install on WSL directly using PyPi or using docker-compose? Based on that answer will vary. Airflow binaries within containers/pods run under user airflow with user id defaulting to 50000.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close! I think your local python (and your terminal whenever you tried `airflow db init` ) was not able to see the airflow you installed on its path.

There is this video series I go to, whenever I need to install Airflow for a fellow coworker.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDDMm9M6SFA) shows how to install Airflow locally. Also, in the [second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mge56uGRagc) video it shows how to write a DAG.

And more importantly, on the third video it shows [how to connect to a different database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HXppV-UCv0) just like you wanted.